# How to upload images of CKedior in Angular2 - Meteor project?

Tags: angular, meteor, ckeditor, image-uploading

How are you.
I am developing angular-meteor project and I have to add local images to ckeditor and they should be uploaded to server.
I implemented ckeditor using ng2-ckeditor.
This is template code.

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent" [readonly]="false" (change)="onChange($event)" (ready)="onReady($event)" (focus)="onFocus($event)"
  (blur)="onBlur($event)" debounce="500">
</ckeditor>
```

Not it work well and but I can insert images only from url.
what I want is to add image from my local computer and upload it to server.
Also I have to get uploaded images path to save database.
I reviewed CKeditor apis but I can't find how to install image upload plugin in Angular Ckeditor plugin.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you very much for you consideration.
Regards.